# How to subtract dates in a column with todays date?

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

The first code below works - my excl file has a column full of dates under a column named Date. I would like to subtract today with Date to get the difference between the two but I get an error in the second code you see below but I'm not sure why.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

now = datetime.date.today()
today = '{0:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(now).format(now)

#Read excel file
excl = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Anaconda\Book1.xlsx')

#Create new column w/data
excl['new_pop'] = (excl.Pop2010 + excl.Pop2020)


#Create new excel file with old and new data
excl.to_excel("fie.xlsx")



excl['age'] = (today - excl.Date)
```

Comment: It would be better if you post the error as well as mention which part of the code is first or second

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert datetime columns to datetime object (compatible with python datetime) using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) which will help you to do datetime arithmetic like python datetime.

```
now = datetime.date.today()
today = '{0:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(now).format(now)

#Read excel file
excl = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Gomez Family\Desktop\Anaconda\Book1.xlsx')

#Create new column w/data
excl['new_pop'] = (excl.Pop2010 + excl.Pop2020)


#Create new excel file with old and new data
excl.to_excel("fie.xlsx")


excl['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(excl['Date']) # See parameters for date formatting
excl['age'] = (today - excl.Date)
```